# I am having some trouble understanding this varargs code example

Tags: java, overloading

```
public class OverloadingVarargs2 {
    static void f(float i, Character... c) {
        System.out.println("first");
    }
    static void f( Character... args) {
        System.out.println("second");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f(1,'a');
        f('a','b');
    }
}
```

I cannot get why is this not working 
I mean the error is "The method f(float, Character[]) is ambiguous for the type OverloadingVarargs2"

Comment: I would recommend to use different method names to avoid the confusion all together.

Comment: wow, talk about exact duplicates! across 2 years no less! must be a question from the same class.